# Credit Card Date Validation MM/YYYY Format

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I need help with a piece of JavaScript, I am trying to make a date validation script which won't allow anything past a certain date, here is what I have so far;

This is where a customer can choose what date their Credit Card expires

```
Expiry MM/YYYY
<select id="expiry" name='expiry'>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
/
<select id="expiry" name='expiry'>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</p>
</select>
```

and here is my if/else statement to let it past or block it

```
function validateForm()
{
var currentDate = new Date();
var month = currentDate.getMonth(5)+1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear(2016);
if (expiry < currentDate)
{
    alert("The date is not valid");
    expiry.focus();
    return false;
}

alert("Thank you for your order");
return true;
}
```

Currently it is letting it past even if the date is past today's date, if you can help, thank you.

Much obliged

-Traigh Warren

Comment: Why do you have two elements both with `id="expiry"` and both with `name='expiry'`? What is the `expiry` variable in your JavaScript function? Where is it defined, is it global, where do you set its value, is it a `Date` value?

Comment: Also, one of my cards expires in 2029...

Comment: Why do you set arguments for the `getMonth` and `getFullYear` functions? Those functions do not have any parameters. And why do you even make it possible to select dates before today's date?

Comment: Will be interesting to do a console.log on the expiry to see what value it is. In my opinion that variable could be the source of your problem.

Comment: The `expiry` variable is probably never set. Please provide a JSFiddle so we can better help you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a link to a working example at the bottom.**

You weren't getting the value of the selected drop downs and your comparisons were off. You also had an expiry id for both. This should make you code more readable.

```
window.validateForm = function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth(5)+1;
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(2016);

  var expireMonth = parseInt(monthExpiry.value);
  var expireYear  = parseInt(yearExpiry.value);

    if ( (currentYear >= expireYear) && (currentMonth > expireMonth) ) {
    alert("The date is not valid");
    return false;
    }

    alert("Thank you for your order");
    return true;
}
```

Here is an example of it working.
https://jsfiddle.net/urxdvtcu/2/
If this is the answer you want, press the green tick.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(expirydate.getTime()<currentDate .getTime())
{
    alert("The date is not valid");

}
```

Compare date by converting it to time.

Answer (score -1):

Here is complete code-

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<select id="expiry_1" name='expiry_1' >
<option value="">Select Month</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
/
<select id="expiry_2" name='expiry_2'>
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</p>
</select>


<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var expiry_1 =  $('#expiry_1').val();
    var expiry_2 =  $('#expiry_2').val();

    if(expiry_1!=""&&expiry_2!=""){
         var currentDate = new Date();
        var cur_time = currentDate.getTime();

        var expire_date =  expiry_1+"/01/"+expiry_2; // i am assuming i will check from the start of the month
        var expire_dateObject = new Date(expire_date);
        var expiry_time = expire_dateObject.getTime();
        if (expiry_time < cur_time)
        {
            alert("The date is not valid");
            $('#expiry_1').focus();
            return false;
        }

        alert("Thank you for your order");
        return true; 
    }

}

$(function(){

    $('#expiry_1').change(function(){

        validateForm();

    });

     $('#expiry_2').change(function(){

        validateForm();

    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code...

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkDate() {
        var EnteredDate = document.getElementById("txtdate").value; 


        var month = EnteredDate.substring(5, 7);
        var day = EnteredDate.substring(8, 10);
        var year = EnteredDate.substring(0, 4);

        var today = new Date();

        if (day < today.getUTCDate() || month < today.getUTCMonth()+1 || year < today.getUTCFullYear()) {
            alert("Entered date is past! ");

        }
        else {
            alert("Entered date is Future ");

        }
    }
    </script>
```